# Spot instance fails to mount EFS volume

Tags: amazon-ec2

I can launch an on-demand EC2 instance and mount my EFS volume with complete success.

However when I try this using a spot instance using exactly the same configuration I find this in the system log...

mount.nfs4: Failed to resolve server fs-9273b65b.efs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com: Name or service not known

If I log into the instance and check /etc/fstab the mount is there and if I then execute "sudo mount -a" the volume mounts without a hitch.

It would appear that at the instant the cloud-config script runs to mount that volume the name does not resolve but a few minutes later can be resolved without error.

Any guidance greatly appreciated.

Comment: Putting a 10 second sleep in the cloud-init script right after runcmd may have alleviated this.  Seems a bit of a hack though.